# How make 2 texture in same mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have this armchair and I would like to make this colored texture, but I tried to select the meshes, and assign the materials, but it doesn't look the same due to the mesh line not being in sync with the texture, I would like to know which is the best truck for
I have this armchair and I would like to make this colored texture, but I tried to select the meshes, and assign the materials, but it doesn't look the same due to the mesh line not being in sync with the texture, I would like to know which is the best way for make this

[image: Left what I want, right my texture]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is actually fairly simple, it's something I had trouble figuring out the beginning too.

- Click on the object you want to texture. Then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and go into *Edit Mode*.
- On the menu on the right side, hit the texture button.
- Hit new (if you don't have one on it yet) and then hit the + to add a second one.
- Then hit <kbd>3</kbd> to only select the faces. Then on your object, select the area of faces you want to texture differently.
- Then go back to the texture panel. Hit the new texture, and then hit assign.

From there, the faces you selected can now be textured differently. Hope this helps.